# Store password in session, It's secure?

Tags: php, session, password-hash

Using PHP, I have a password in the form password_hash
Is storing it in session considered secure?

What do you advise me to increase security?

Thanks

Comment: Not too sure on whether it poses a security issue. However, if once the user is logged in, what's the point to store the password anywhere?

Comment: Whilst sessions are usually secure, it is possible to hijack them if your security is lax or some mistake is made. But really it's irrelevant - why do you want to store the password in the session to begin with? What are you going to use that for? There should never be any reason for this. The password should be carried in PHP variables at registration time, at login time, and perhaps at password reset time, and just passed direct to the database during that script. There should never be any reason to hold it, show it, or do anything else with it.